# Sync between 2 goroutines

Tags: go

My task is to sync 2 goroutines so the output should look like that:

> foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar

.The issue is that when I call them they come out completely randomized. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ConcurrentPrinter struct {
    sync.WaitGroup
    sync.Mutex
}


func (cp *ConcurrentPrinter) printFoo(times int) {
    cp.WaitGroup.Add(times)
    go func() {
        cp.Lock()
        fmt.Print("foo")
        cp.Unlock()
    }()
}
func (cp *ConcurrentPrinter) printBar(times int) {
    cp.WaitGroup.Add(times)
    go func() {
        cp.Lock()
        fmt.Print("bar")
        cp.Unlock()
    }()
}

func main() {
    times := 10
    cp := &ConcurrentPrinter{}

    for i := 0; i <= times; i++ {
        cp.printFoo(i)
        cp.printBar(i)
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of the output order in go routines. If you want to alternate between the two, you'll need to implement that (a channel can do the trick). You are also calling a lot of cp.WaitGroup.Add(${numbers}). You should call cp.WaitGroup.Done() in every go func() {...}; and, finally, you should call cp.WaitGroup.Wait() instead of time.Sleep

Comment: There's a very simple way to make sure statements run in the order you want: run them serially, not concurrently.   Your use case seems contrived and not a very good real world example of concurrency.

Comment: Can you post more details of the larger task you want to achieve. Utilizing goroutines is tempting but not always the best fit or even performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the comments, using goroutines may not be the best use case for what you are trying to achieve - and thus this may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Having said that, if you want to ensure two independent goroutines interleave their work in an alternating sequence, you can implement a set of "ping-pong" mutexs:

```
var ping, pong sync.Mutex

pong.Lock() // ensure the 2nd goroutine waits & the 1st goes first

go func() {
    for {
        ping.Lock()
        foo()
        pong.Unlock()
    }
}()

go func() {
    for {
        pong.Lock()
        bar()
        ping.Unlock()
    }
}()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/VO2LoMJ8fek

Answer (score 1):

Using channel:

```
func printFoo(i int, ch chan<- bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Print("foo")
        ch <- true
    }()
}
func printBar(i int, ch chan<- bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Print("bar")
        ch <- true
    }()

}

func main() {
    times := 4
    firstchan := make(chan bool)
    secondchan := make(chan bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i <= times; i++ {
        printFoo(i, firstchan, &wg)
        <-firstchan
        printBar(i, secondchan, &wg)
        <-secondchan
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/MlZ9dHkUXGb

Comment: There is no need to use WaitGroup and you can delete it. If you run the Loop anonymously in the Goroutine, you need it by adding it to Wait and Done after the Loop is finished.

Comment: Yes true, I agree